# Android UI layout Onclick listener

Tags: android, android-layout

i have one layout like this
[image]

when click in layer1,layer 2 get invisible but when i click on layer2 it do not go to invisible.
i use the following code,but it's not working,when i click layer2 it also go to invisible, any idea to get visible of layer2 when i click layer2.

```
 RelativeLayout layout1=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.hidebg);
         final RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.hidelayer);
         layout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(layout.getVisibility()==0)
            {
                layout.setVisibility(4);
            }
            else
            {
                layout.setVisibility(0);
            }

            }
        });
```

Comment: make sure have you declared i as static at class level field?

Comment: yes i declared the variable "i" at top of the class

Comment: i think you will need to set setOnClickListener also for layout

Comment: remove final Keyword from relative layout

Comment: don't use hardcoded values, there are constants for that. -1 for (almost) ultimate bad practice

Comment: also you can test the visibility with getVisibility, it is useless and dangerous to create a variable only to store an existing information (with different constant values, which is even worse)

Comment: @njzk2 hi now check i altered my code as you say...is there any idea about how to implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add event listener on the second layout

```
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    layout.setVisibility(4);
                    i=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    layout.setVisibility(0);
                    i=0;
                }

            }
        });
```

Then check.

Answer (score 4):

set layer2 as visible by default and use this code :

```
layer1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(layer2.getvisibility==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    layer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                else
                {
                    layer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: thankyou for ur reply, but i ask when i click layer2 it did not go to invsible...

Comment: replace gone with invisible and add a listener on layer 2 and copy this code for layer2 also....